# C - Case statement failing to compare variable

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm a little confused with the case statement in the PrintGenre function; it passes the value correctly, but defaults to Undefined.

Little bit of background; this is ultimately becoming a (very simple) text music player, and I think I've found an easier way to do this, but just for my overall understanding I wanted to figure out why this case statement isn't functioning the way I wanted it to.

If I remove the default option, it goes to the last case option in the list.

I'm fairly new to the C language, so if there's anything I'm misunderstanding please let me know.

```
#include "terminal_user_input.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum musicGenre {Pop, Alternative_Rock, Electronic, Undefined};

struct Album
{
    my_string Title;
    my_string Artist;
    int Year;
    enum musicGenre Genre;
};

my_string PrintGenre(int Genre)
{
    //Variables
    my_string result;
    printf("%d", Genre); //outputs correctly
    switch (Genre)
    {
        case 0:
            strcpy(result.str, "Pop");
        case 1: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Alternative Rock");
        case 2: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Electronic");
        default: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Undefined");
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    // Variables
    struct Album Album1;
    int choice;

    printf("1. Pop\n");
    printf("2. Alternative Rock\n");
    printf("3. Electronic\n");
    choice = read_integer("Please select a genre: ");

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Album1.Genre = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            Album1.Genre = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            Album1.Genre = 2;
            break;
        default:
            Album1.Genre = 3;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d", Album1.Genre);
    printf("The genre of Album 1 is %s", PrintGenre(Album1.Genre).str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not have skipped the chapter about the `switch` statement in your C book. If you're learning C by youtube or similar: get a good book instead!

Comment: Currently studying it at university; not my proudest moment :')

Comment: Strong advice: use a good book about **mordern C** (i.e. at least C99, better standard C11) as supplement. Many tutors are somewhat stuck with ancient C (no offence to your teacher, but my observation).

Comment: I'll take a look into it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
switch (Genre)
{
    case 0:
        strcpy(result.str, "Pop");
    case 1: 
        strcpy(result.str, "Alternative Rock");
    case 2: 
        strcpy(result.str, "Electronic");
    default: 
        strcpy(result.str, "Undefined");
}
```

all the case statements bodies are missing a `break;` statement, which makes it a ***[fall-through switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough)***.

To avoid this "undesired" behaviour, you need to add a `break;` statement every time you want to limit the flow of program to a certain part of the body.

Quoting the example from the `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.4.2/P7

> EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>       int i = 4;
>       f(i);
>
>   case 0:
>       i = 17;
>       /* falls through into default code */   << --- NOTE HERE
>
>   default:
>
>   printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```

Comment: Oh wow! The fix was super simple. Thank you, I was really confused on where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

add `break`;

```
switch (Genre)
    {
        case 0:
            strcpy(result.str, "Pop"); break;
        case 1: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Alternative Rock"); break;
        case 2: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Electronic"); break;
        default: 
            strcpy(result.str, "Undefined");
    }
```